# I am unable to run container in docker

Tags: dockerfile, docker-container

I have written a docker file it has been executed successfully but when I try to run an image, the container has been existed and I got an error is " Error: Unable to access jar file iot_daily_aggregation_0_1.jar". so, can anyone please help to sort it out?

THANK YOU.

I am unable to run the container.it has to run always.